# What make an API can only called from a server side and also unavailable from client side

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure but I was working with google RSS and there's a case where I have to access an API and if I fetch it from the client side it will return Cors error but when I access it from a node server it works

Comment: By default browsers don't allow access to APIs of other domains. This restriction can be turned off with CORS. If there's no CORS, there's no access.

Answer (score -1):

That's because of what's called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) . It's a way of preventing the server from unknown clients/requests.

There is a package called cors - (you can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)) - that allows your server to accept client requests by configuring it